# Retrieve JPEG binary in LDAP with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ldap, base64

I have a problem to display an jpeg image (for user profile) uing nodeJS and [LDAP Module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/LDAP)

So my code is :

```
            ldap.search(search_options, function(err, data){
                if (err) console.log ('Error getting LDAP: ' + err);
                else
                {
                    data.sort(dynamicSort('uid'));
                    data.forEach(function(elem)
                    {
                        if (elem['picture'] != undefined)
                        {
                            console.log(elem['picture'][0]);
                            elem['picture'][0] = btoa(elem['picture'][0]); // Doesn't modify in good format
                            console.log(elem['picture'][0]);
                        }
                });
```

I get 4 unknown symbols on the logger and when i encode them in base 64 i get "/f39/Q==" for every picture (which is wrong cause they're all different).

Is it a problem retrieving jpg data ? (someone did it using buffer in search but i didn't get it) or is it a problem decoding the data ?

Thanks for the answers

Comment: I suggest you find out what the value is before encoding. Could be interesting.

Comment: It is a jpeg binary data (unprintable chars) but i'm not sure to retrieve it properly, looks like this LDAP search doesn't give me the good file.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm dealing with this right now, and it's quite frustrating :(

Comment: Related: https://github.com/mcavage/node-ldapjs/issues/137